# Adjectives to describe a person that looks clueless/lost

Tags: single-word-requests

As in the title, what's a word to describe a person who looks clueless or lost? As in the person looks like they don't know anything. However, in this context, I don't mean the person is dim-witted, nor slow. It's just that they have this expression on their faces that somehow displays a lack of understanding.

EDIT: Forgive me, but to clarify, I don't mean the person looks confused.

I was thinking of "Guys from that country always look so blank".

But is "blank" the right word to use here? If, so please let me know as well as any other words you can think of.

Comment: What has your previous research revealed? Thesaurus.com suggests *absent, disoriented, misplaced, astray and wandering* as synonyms for lost, do any of them fit? Anyway why does **lost** not fit?

Comment: Would you believe so out of it? Gormless, is a good one.

Comment: @BladorthinTheGrey Lost does fit. I wanted to add words to my repertoire. But those synonyms do not fit in this case. It's gotta be "That guy looks so ______". You can't say "That guys looks so absent", can you?

Comment: Er, [yes](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=looks+absent&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Clooks%20absent%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: Yeah, but that's got a different meaning to what I wanted to convey. [http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/absent_1?q=absent]

Comment: @BladorthinTheGrey [https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/absent] Sorry, I meant to post this definition

Comment: I would say that personally, absent seems to fit, but empirically perhaps [absent-minded](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/absent-minded) is better.

Comment: One can refer to a person physically, mentally, or both. "Absent" when referring to someone physically present clearly refers to their mind.

Comment: As in the title, please don't say "person that". As in the question, please stick with "person who".

Answer (score 2):

If you look at [synonyms](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/all%20at%20sea) for ***at sea*** or ***all at sea*** you'll find lots of examples like *bewildered*, *befuddled*, *perplexed* and *disoriented*, any of which might fit your sentence.

Answer (score 1):

***Bewildered*** - Lost in pathless places, at a loss for one's way; fig. confused mentally.  Pathless, trackless, mazy; utterly confused or tangled. (OED)

Comment: May it not please the OED, but really: you are + trackless or + mazy? For a person? Or is that just you?